# Hydrating ngrx app from URL params

Tags: angular, ngrx

Am trying to write an app that applies filters to a list of data. I store the filters in the url to enable deep linking to pre-specified values. The code below - from `filters.component.ts` - reads and processes the url on load, and updates the url on changes to the filters (via the form elements).

My issue is that when the app loads, `ngOnChanges` is called with the bootstrap value of the ngrx state. This corresponds to a url of "/" and my code causes a navigation to take place that overwrites whatever might have been in the url.

I've got around it with the if-statement below, but as this is a hacky I fear I have made a more fundamental design choice and would welcome recommendations to do this more idiomatically - I think that means **how can I hydrate my app with data from the router?**.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      this.action.next({
        type: NEW_FILTERS,
        payload: fromUrl(params['filter'])
      })
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (typeof changes['filters'].previousValue.budget != 'undefined') {
      this.cmpFilters = Object.assign({}, this.filters);

      let link = ['/recommendations', toUrl( this.cmpFilters)];
      this.router.navigate(link);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

ngOnChanges is called once before ngOnInit and every time an input property is changed. Though this solution doesn't get rid of your if statement, it does make it more readable.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.initialized = true;
  this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
    this.action.next({
      type: NEW_FILTERS,
      payload: fromUrl(params['filter'])
    })
  });
}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (this.initialized) {
    this.cmpFilters = Object.assign({}, this.filters);
    let link = ['/recommendations', toUrl( this.cmpFilters)];
    this.router.navigate(link);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, as you note this does not address whether a deeper understanding angular bootstrapping could be applied

Comment: Yes, but it does remove the "hacky" part of your solution. Its very common to use an if statement to ignore calls in ngOnChanges. They use this pattern throughout their source code. Here’s one example: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/router/src/directives/router_link_active.ts#L107